# "Symmetric" GROUP BY on multiple columns

Tags: sql, group-by, symmetric

I have a table like that:

```
_id sender_id receiver_id text
1   1         2           xxx
2   2         1           yyy
3   1         2           xyz
4   3         1           abc
```

I need to do a GROUP BY on both the `sender_id` and `receiver_id` columns, but it should be symmetric, so {1,2} and {2,1} should be considered as the same group.

This query could be executed on a random DBMS so it should be as most standard as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need *two* `CASE` expressions here, since you are grouping on two columns:

```
GROUP BY CASE WHEN sender_id < receiver_id THEN sender_id
              ELSE receiver_id
         END,
         CASE WHEN sender_id < receiver_id THEN receiver_id
              ELSE sender_id
         END,
```

If you are using MySQL, then consider using the `LEAST()`, `GREATEST()` trick:

```
SELECT LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id), GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY LEAST(sender_id, receiver_id), GREATEST(sender_id, receiver_id)
```

In SQLite you can use `MAX()` and `MIN()` as [*scalar* functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html):

```
SELECT MIN(sender_id, receiver_id), MAX(sender_id, receiver_id)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY MIN(sender_id, receiver_id), MAX(sender_id, receiver_id)
```

Comment: Thank you! Does Sqlite support LEAST and GREATEST?

Comment: `least` and `greatest` aren't ANSI SQL, and in fact, aren't widely supported either. `case` is a better choice for Alessandro's purposes.

Comment: Also, worth bearing in mind, `LEAST()` and `GREATEST()` don't behave intuitively *(read: the same as `MIN()` and `MAX()`)* when dealing with `NULL`s.  More importantly, they have different numbers of characters and don't line up nicely, meaning that using `CASE` is prettier ;)